# Angular: Adding custom script/css to partials via controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to add custom page CSS/JS to my partials via controllers, i have created a custom directive for it but when i am loading the CSS using it it gets unnecessary parameters which i don't want, and when i load JS using it my JS does not load the the right time(meaning the init functions written in the page gets called before, leaving the error)

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('head', ['$rootScope','$compile',
    function($rootScope, $compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, elem){
                var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" ng-repeat="(routeCtrl, cssUrl) in routeStyles" ng-href="{{cssUrl}}" />';
                elem.append($compile(html)(scope));
                scope.routeStyles = {};
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, next, current) {
                    if(current && current.$$route && current.$$route.css){
                        if(!Array.isArray(current.$$route.css)){
                            current.$$route.css = [current.$$route.css];
                        }
                        angular.forEach(current.$$route.css, function(sheet){
                            delete scope.routeStyles[sheet];
                        });
                    }
                    if(next && next.$$route && next.$$route.css){
                        if(!Array.isArray(next.$$route.css)){
                            next.$$route.css = [next.$$route.css];
                        }
                        angular.forEach(next.$$route.css, function(sheet){
                            scope.routeStyles[sheet] = sheet;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

**APP CONTROLLER**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/some/route/1', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', 
            controller: 'Partial1Ctrl',
            css: 'css/partial1.css'
        })
        .when('/some/route/2', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html',
            controller: 'Partial2Ctrl',
            css: ['css/partial2_1.css','css/partial2_2.css']
        })
}]);
```

**Output I am getting**

*CSS*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-repeat="(routeCtrl, cssUrl) in routeStyles" ng-href="css/createtroll.css" class="ng-scope" href="css/partial2.css">
```

*HTML*

```
<script ng-repeat="(routeCtrl, scriptUrl) in routeScript" ng-src="js/page.css" class="ng-scope" src="css/scroll.js"></script>
```

I want know how to remove the ng-directives form the output and how to load js before document.ready so that I don't get the error. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you are looking for a way to lazy-load some aspect of our AngularJS application by loading JS and CSS files asynchronously.

You cannot use controllers/directives for loading your files because your app has already been bootstrapped.

You'll need some kind of file/module loader, for example you can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) - a JavaScript file and module loader.
there are already a lot of examples and implementation of RequireJS and AngularJS.

**Example:**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",    
    paths: {
        'angular': '.../angular.min',
        'angular-route': '.../angular-route.min',
        'angularAMD': '.../angularAMD.min'
    },
    shim: { 'angularAMD': ['angular'], 'angular-route': ['angular'] },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

**Reference:**

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home

http://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-Loading-AngularJS-Components-With-RequireJS-After-Application-Bootstrap.htm

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Is there a demo on how to achieve this using require and angular??

Comment: as you can see I added some reference articles with examples.

Comment: but still haven't haven't figured out a gud solution for CSS do you know??

Comment: using require.js you can also add css files, 
I found this example : http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css

Comment: this function i'll have to call from the partial, i don't want to do that, it will defeat the whole purpose. I want to do it form the routers.

Comment: I understand but as you can see you can load js/modules using require.js but adding css you need to play with it , here you have some plugin for embedding/adding css using require :https://github.com/tyt2y3/requirejs-css-plugin